# conversion of long string to and from short url-friendly string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, web, compression

Here's my situation:

I have an MVC website with links to various "things" that exist in my data store.  Like many websites, I want to have short, descriptive urls for these things, for example `www.mysite.com/12/description-of-thing` where the "12" in the url represents the key to the data in the datastore.

I'm currently working with a noSQL solution as opposed to a RDBMS, so instead of short integer keys to the data, I have these long, contrived, fixed-length keys that act as a clustered index to the data.  A url for such a thing in my project might look like this: `www.mysite.com/000_sub_2520552274112731878_497d19e/description-of-thing`.  Obviously, this is not a nice, short url.

What I'm looking for is to have some sort of bi-directional conversion from something like "000_sub_2520552274112731878_497d19e" to some much shorter, url-friendly string.

Is something like this possible?  Do any solutions already exist?

Comment: Since I'm working with a NoSQL solution, I'm unable to have alternate keys for things.  Having to take a trip to a db to reference a numerical key with the *actual* key would defeat the purpose of using a NoSql solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compress the information into a shorter string without a table look-up, especially if you know that the structure of "000_sub_2520552274112731878_497d19e" is consistent.  I don't know what your criteria are for "much shorter".

For example, if you know it will be ddd`_sub_`dddddddddddddddddd`_`hhhhhhh where d is a decimal digit and h is a hexadecimal digit, then you can code the first ddd in 10 bits, the second set of d's in 64 bits, and the last set of h's in 28 bits.  You don't code the `_sub_` or `_`, since you know they are always there.  You have 102 bits total, which you can now code in 17 characters in base 64 (less than half the original length), or 16 characters in base 85.  I haven't checked, but there should be a set of 85 URL-safe characters.

If you don't know the structure of that key, then the amount of compression will be rather less, but you can still get some.

Comment: I do know the structure of the key, so this should work.  I could also optimize the key to be better suited for this conversion.  The first 3 digits have an upper-bound of 100 so they could actually be stored in a single byte, the next set of d's can be changed to 0-padded 32-bit integer and the remaining h's are actually unnecessary.  My reasoning might be naive, but I'm thinking I could store all necessary data in a single unsigned 32-bit integer, which could then be converted to a a nice base-52 number.  Anyway, I really appreciate you setting me down the right path.

Comment: 100 can be stored in 7 bits.  I don't know what you mean by "0-padded 32-bit integer".  The 19 digits look like a 64-bit integer to me.

Comment: I can change the 19-digit 0-padded number to a 10 digit 0-padded number that represents a signed 32-bit integer, and I can drop the '_hhhhhhh' altogether.  Having made this change, I'm now storing the key as a 13-character string with no underscores.  I think I could encode this into 4 bytes that could then be interpreted as an unsigned integer and converted to a base-52 string.

Comment: scratch that, will need to be encoded into 5 bytes.  Either way, I got it figured out.  Thanks.